# Flutter Bloc for navigation flow

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting started with the BLoC pattern but I have a question:

1) Should you use the BloC pattern to determine if the routes should change?
Example: authentication object changes to `unauthenticated` so the listeners should handle the route changes.

2) Should the BLoC pattern only be used for UI state and handle the route changes on UI changes?
Example: User clicks on `login` and navigates to the `home` screen.

I ask this question because I'm facing a problem where I don't have a central navigation management solution.

This code is in my BLoC now:

```
loggedIn.listen((AuthResponse user) {
      currentUserSubject.add(user);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        _context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
            return HomePage();
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, _, child) {
            return new SlideTransition(
              child: child,
              position: new Tween<Offset>(
                begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                end: Offset.zero,
              ).animate(animation),
            );
          },
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        ),
      );
    }, onError: (error) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(error.message),
      ));
    });
```

Comment: I've actually done this and am interested to see others' opinions on it. In my case there where only about 4 screens in the app and four nav buttons to change the page, so it was unnecessary overhead. If there are many pages and users have multiple ways of changing them, then it may be worthwhile.

Another con is that nav BLoCs don't translate well to the web, at least not without complicating how an `<a></a>` works without screwing up SEO.

Comment: Check what I have right now in the EDIT

Answer (score 2):

What I'm currently doing is:

1. Register a `NavigatorBloc` that receive a `NavigatorState` in the constructor and receive actions to navigate to different pages in your app Ex: `GoToHomePageAction`, `GoToRegisterPageAction`, `NavigatorActionPop`.

In your App widget you register the `NavigatorBloc` and provide the navigator key attached to the `MaterialApp` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<NavigatorBloc>(
      bloc: NavigatorBloc(navigatorKey: widget.navigatorKey),
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: widget.navigatorKey,
        title: 'Medicine Tracker',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then in side your `NavigatorBloc` you just check the the action and navigate to the desired page:

```
class NavigatorBloc extends Bloc<NavigatorAction, dynamic>{
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  NavigatorBloc({this.navigatorKey});

  @override
  dynamic get initialState => 0;

  @override
  Stream<dynamic> mapEventToState(NavigatorAction event) async* {
    if(event is NavigatorActionPop){
      yield navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are 2 Yes/No questions there (in contrast to W/H questions), and my answers are yes to both of them. The reason being that with BloC and navigation, you can actually recover the current screen if the app crashes (auto-save state and state recover must be in place, but it's another W/H question), and other nice features of BLoC/event-based state management (history snapshot, time machine, event replay, separate of concerns, testability, etc.)

> I ask this question because I'm facing a problem where I don't have a central navigation management solution.

Is there anything I can help with regarding your problem?